# Loading the php file in xammp server

Tags: php

I am making a website by using "xampp" server. But when i go to personal information page and try to open the "View plan details file",it gives me the php code that i have written in notepad editor.Instead it should give me the output of that code.What kind of this problem can be?

Comment: Your server probably has not set PHP as possible language and such will see it as plain text. Check you server settings.

Answer (score -1):

first check Xampp Server Running (apache ,mysql) if not then start both apache and mysql

your browser url should be 
http://localhost/filename

or else post your code, so we can check where you wrong.